# Deleted Pages URI Module and my site crashed..!

Tags: pages

I had an issue with my MSM where it didnt allow me to "Submit" my entry and I have googled for the error and then I came across an answer which said to delete the "Pages" module. I did so and I didnt realize that I was going to hit hard by that step. Alfter I did that all my URLs got messed up.

I have around 1000 channels which basically make up my college website.

Is there anyway I can restore all the URLs..?? Please help me out with this.

Its really urgent and Please Please Please help me out ...!!

Comment: @Alex Kendrick: yeah its a duplicate. its just that I'm in a difficult situation and trying out for answers and so posted the same question 2 times. Do you have any thoughts..?

Comment: I totally understand and am sorry you're in that situation! Just trying to prevent confusion by marking as a duplicate. Your best bet is a backup as John pointed out in his answer on the other post. Recreating thousands of Page URI's by hand is not going to be fun.